# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-livedata

I use Android architecture components and tried to instantiate viewmodel and Observe data from LiveData. But im getting the following error :

ActivationFragment.clas:

```
@OnClick(R.id.btn_activation)
public void onEvaluateClick(Button v) {
    maActivationCode = etActivation.getText().toString();
    mActiationViewModel.getsatusCode(maActivationCode).observe(this, new Observer<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable Boolean aBoolean) {
        } 
    });
}
```

ActivationViewModel class:

```
public class ActivationViewModel  extends ViewModel{

public ActivationRepository activationRepository;

public ActivationViewModel(ActivationRepository activationRepository) {
    this.activationRepository = activationRepository;
}

public LiveData<Boolean> getsatusCode(String activationCode) {
    return (LiveData<Boolean>)  activationRepository.getStatusCode(activationCode);
}
```

}

ActivationRepository class:

```
public class ActivationRepository {

public MutableLiveData<Boolean> status;

public MutableLiveData<Boolean> getStatusCode(String activationCode) {
    status.setValue(Boolean.valueOf(false));
    return status;
}
```

Comment: where did you use `setValue` post that code.. please

Comment: I tried with  status.setvalue(Boolean.valueOf(false)); but same output...see my edit please

Comment: i have updated the code.. try it.. your `ActivationRepository`

Comment: update if it works

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update your function like this..

```
public class ActivationRepository {

public MutableLiveData<Boolean> status = new MutableLiveData<>();

 public MutableLiveData<Boolean> getStatusCode(String activationCode) {
    status.postValue(Boolean.valueOf(false));
    return status;
}
```

Comment: Omg,  what a lame mistake, It works as this , thanks a lot

Comment: update ..the answer.. if it worked.. btw how r you ? i dint get time..could nt look at your git project.. :(

Comment: Y i will check as correct, I am fine, how r u, I fixed that  project, so no worries:)

Comment: the problem was not `postValue()` which is prefered in general (because it runs not on the mainthread in comparison to `setValue()`). You just forgot to initialize your status object with `new MutableLiveData<>();` A somewhat misleading error message ;)